# How to create program guide based on Android Tv Input Framework, as below shown diagram

Tags: channel, android-tv, epg

I downloaded the google project from git repo link: **https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-sample-inputs**. But I am unable to find the understanding of module for the below-mentioned layout. I need to create channel and EPG view exactly same as the below-mentioned diagram, using the android lean-back library and TV Input framework concepts. So, kindly provide me with the understanding of the project as where I can find the working of this module.

[image]

Comment: A TV input service represents a media stream source, and lets you present your media content in a linear, broadcast TV fashion as channels and programs. With a TV input service, you can provide parental controls, program guide information, and content ratings. The TV input service works with the Android system TV app. This app ultimately controls and presents channel content on the TV. The system TV app is developed specifically for the device and immutable by third-party apps. You can check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/tvinput) for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guide you see here is part of a reference TV App aka Live Channels which is a system app and ships with every Android TV system image. It is open-sourced under Apache 2.0 and you can check out the details and source code here:

https://source.android.com/devices/tv/reference-tv-app
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TV/

It uses a different build system than Gradle but you should be able to refactor it to use Gradle.

EDIT: A nice alternative TV guide for Android TV recently appeared on GitHub here: https://github.com/egeniq/android-tv-program-guide